# Add new items to a nested list in form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making a simple app for inventory manager, using C# .NET Core 3.1 MVC and I faced a barrier

I have a class called Product that have a list of collors

```
public class Product : Entity
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Collor> Collors { get; set; } = new List<Collor>();
}
```

my class Collor only have a property called Description

I'm making a form for Products and I wanted it to have an "Add collor" button, that once clicked add a new Collor to the Collors list with a delete button, but I'm struggling to do so, this is my view

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <h4>Collors</h4>
            @{
                foreach (var collor in Model.Collors)
                {
                    <partial name="_Collor" model="collor" />
                }
                <input type="button" value="Add Collor" class="btn btn-success" />
            }
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

and here is my partial for collor form

```
@model MyApp.Models.Collor
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

how do I make the button "Add collor" to create a new item in the list dynamiclly?

Comment: That kind of functionality is generally done with a frontend technology.  Jquery makes this pretty simple.  It gets a bit tougher since you are rendering the collors using a partial view (which would require the entire page to be rebuilt afaik)

Comment: Hi @Rodrigofp, did you want to add a new item to color which does not exist in color list? In your view, it does not contain any code to add description of new color.

Comment: oh, sorry @Rena, my Collor class implements Entity and have a property called Description

Comment: Hi @Rodrigofp, maybe you misunderstand what I ask. Any way, please check my answer below if it meets your requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo about how to dynamic add new item to color list:

View ( Index.cshtml in my project):

```
@model Product
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h4>Collors</h4>
    <div id="colorlist">
        @{
            foreach (var collor in Model.Collors)
            {
                <partial name="_Collor" model="collor" />
            }
        }
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateColor()" value="Add Collor" class="btn btn-success" />
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function CreateColor() {
        $('#colorlist').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Description</label><input name="Description" class="form-control input-sm" /><input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /></div >')
        $('.btn-danger').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
        })
    };
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new Products()
    {
        Collors = collors   //set color data for the partial view
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Products product, IFormCollection form)
{
    //initialize the property
    product.Collors = new List<Collor>();
    //get the data from form
    var color = form["Description"].ToArray();
    foreach (var value in color)
    {
        product.Collors.Add(new Collor() { Description = value });
    }
    //do your stuff...
    return View("Index");
}
```